# Extra height pixels in simple div with img

Tags: javascript

I am having difficulty determining where the extra pixels of height are coming from for the div in this simple layout. My expectation would be that the image would determine the height of the div but instead it appears to be a few pixels larger. The pixels I am trying to get rid of are shown in blue. Any ideas?

Oh, I have added a button to explicitly set the height of the image parent div properly using javascript - my question is really where is it getting that extra height from in the first place, or how can I do this without javascript?

```js
function change() {
  var image = document.getElementById('image1ID');
  var width = image.naturalWidth;
  var height = image.naturalHeight;
  var imageDIV = document.getElementById('image1DIV');

  imageDIV.style.height = (100 * height / width) + "px";

}
```

```html
<div id="image1DIV" style="background-color:#00f;">
  <img id="image1ID" style="width:100px;" src="http://www.imageno.com/thumbs/20170330/73dlz3sr4pfy.jpg">
</div>

<button onclick="change()">change height of parent div</button>
```

Comment: give `vertical-align: middle` to your `img` tag. The space gets removed.

Comment: Thank you!! That is it! Add it as an answer and I will give you the credit!

Comment: glad it worked. posted it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `vertical-align:middle` to your `img` tag. It removes extra space.

```js
function change() {
  var image = document.getElementById('image1ID');
  var width = image.naturalWidth;
  var height = image.naturalHeight;
  var imageDIV = document.getElementById('image1DIV');

  imageDIV.style.height = (100 * height / width) + "px";

}
```

```css
#image1ID {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="image1DIV" style="background-color:#00f;">
  <img id="image1ID" style="width:100px;" src="http://www.imageno.com/thumbs/20170330/73dlz3sr4pfy.jpg">
</div>

<button onclick="change()">change height of parent div</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

the `img` tag height is not explicitly set to occupy 100% height of its parent. What you are seeing are parts of background color styled on the parent

```
.flexrow img{
      height:100%;
    }
```

Snippet below

```css
.flexrow {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: none;
}

.flexcolumn {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.textblock {
  width: 170px;
}

.flexrow img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexcolumn">

  <div class="flexrow">
    <div style="background-color:#00f;">
      <img style="width:100px;" src="http://www.imageno.com/thumbs/20170330/73dlz3sr4pfy.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="flexcolumn textblock" style="background-color:#eee;">
      <div style="background-color:#e0e;">Title is here</div>
      <div style="background-color:#0ee;">Description is here</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flexrow">
    <div style="background-color:#0f0;">
      <img style="width:100px;" src="http://www.imageno.com/thumbs/20170330/73dlz3sr4pfy.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="flexcolumn textblock" style="background-color:#ee0;">
      <div style="background-color:#e0e;">Title is here</div>
      <div style="background-color:#0ee;">Description is here</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: This merely stretches the image so that it has the wrong aspect ratio. I want the image to maintain its aspect ratio and the parent div to be the same size as it is.

Comment: Then you will always have that extra height of the parent elements bulging out with that color...This is the closest I can get you

Comment: Where is the parent getting its height from? That seems to be the real issue. I can add some javascript and set it explicitly based on the aspect ratio of the image but I am wondering why that would be necessary in this case...

Comment: The fact that you are using a flex display each .flexrow will adjust to the height for their largest sibling which is your div width contents. Their heights are larger than the image that lays beside them

Comment: right - the tallest flexrow component should be the image itself so where is the div getting that taller height from? I just added a button to my example code to explicitly set the height of the image parent div to the height of the image and it all lays out perfectly when i do that - just wondering where the parent div gets that taller height in the first place...

Comment: Or... maybe I read your comment wrong - what do you mean by "largest sibling which is your div width contents" ...?

Comment: my apologies...the sibling with the tallest height

Comment: That is, the div with the contents inside (no image) has the tallest height in the row

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139545/discussion-between-fmacdee-and-repzero).